# Put a numbers from a (n by n) matrix on each cell of a grid

Tags: matlab

I have implemented the A* algorithm to solve the 8-puzzle. However I want to be more fancy by displaying the result of each state change of my 3 by 3 matrix on a grid that animates the state.

My matrix has numbers from 0 to 8, so I want a grid with 3 rows and 3 columns with a number on each tile.

I really do not know where to start, all ideas are welcome.

Below the first matrix is where I have started, and I used A* to reach the last state which is the goal state. I would like to display these matrix on a grid, and show the transitions graphically. So each time the matrix changes, the grid also will change.

```
 2     8     3
 1     6     4
 7     0     5

 2     8     3
 1     0     4
 7     6     5

 2     0     3
 1     8     4
 7     6     5

 0     2     3
 1     8     4
 7     6     5

 1     2     3
 0     8     4
 7     6     5

 1     2     3
 8     0     4
 7     6     5
```

Comment: Can you show us what you *have* and what you *want* as output?

Comment: Are you looking for a GUI or in the command window? What's wrong with `disp`

Comment: Yah, that is right! I am looking for a GUI! nothing is wrong with `disp`, but I would prefer to have a GUI.

Comment: I want to see graphically, possibly in the Matlab fig window as each state changes.

Comment: It is not much about the GUI, but to get the matrix onto a grid so you can see the state changes as the grid updates each time. Something like grid or pcolor, but pcolor does not use 3 by 3 matrix.

Comment: Try `imagesc(your_matrix)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this for example of a use of `imagesc`:

```
P = perms(0:8);
A = reshape(P(1:100,:).',3,[]);
A = reshape(A,3,3,[]);

for k = 1:size(A,3)
    imagesc(A(:,:,k))
    axis off
    pause(0.1)
end
```

[image: opt_1]

if you want to add the borders, you can either pad it with `nan`s:

```
B = nan(5,5,size(A,3));
B(1:2:5,1:2:5,:) = A;
cmap = colormap;
cmap(1,:) = [0 0 0];
colormap(cmap)

for k = 1:size(B,3)
    imagesc(B(:,:,k))
    axis off
    pause(0.1)
end
```

[image: opt_2]

or use `pcolor` (with some padding with `nan`s):

```
B = nan(4,4,size(A,3));
B(1:3,1:3,:) = A;

for k = 1:size(B,3)
    pcolor(B(:,:,k))
    axis off
    pause(0.1)
end
```

[image: opt_3]

Comment: This looks good! How would you add spacing between the cells, or put a border around each cell?

Comment: @Jam1, I added some options, have a look.

Comment: Hey thanks man, I prefer `pcolor`, however I had to add `set(gca, 'Ydir', 'reverse')` because the image was displaying wrong vertically.

Comment: You welcome ;) you can also write `axis ij` or `axis xy` to flip the direction